# Restringir <T> àpenas os atributos preenchidos

Tags: c#, aplicação-desktop

Imaginem a situação em que eu tenho por exemplo 3 objetos de classe distintas:

```
Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
Fornecedor fornecedor = new Fornecedor();
Vendedor vendedor = new Vendedor();
```

E tenho uma função que vai fazer a persistência desses elemetnos em suas respectivas tabelas no banco

```
public void Grava() {
..........
}
```

O problema é que eu gostaria de criar uma função que fosse genérica.

E ate consegui, se não fosse o caso de C# ser fortemente tipada.

O recurso que arrumei que funcionou mais ou menos  é:

```
public bool Grava<T>(T obj) {
...
}
```

Mas a resposta de **T obj** não traz apenas os atributos que populei. Antes, traz também os que eu não preenchi na criação do objeto na condiçao de Null.

Suponha o caso de que

```
Cliente tenha: id, nome, cpf, endereco, login, senha

Fornecedor tenha: id, nome, cpf, empresa, login, senha

Vendedor tenha: id, nome, cpf, setor, login, senha
```

E eu vou criar o cliente por exemplo. então faço:

```
Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
cliente.nome= "José"
cliente.cpf = "1234567800"

Grava(cliente);
```

Mas na hora que esse objeto passa pelo parâmetro, **Grava(T obj)**, embora eu tenha preenchido apenas o **nome** e o **cpf**, mas **obj** passa a ter todos os atributos não preenchidos também.

Como não tem como saber qual vai se o **objeto** que vai passar ali, existe alguma forma de filtrar de forta tal que **T Obj** possua apenas os atributos preenchidos em new Cliente()?

Daí weu faço:

```
var campos = new StringBuilder();
var propiedades = obj.GetType().GetProperties();

foreach (var prop in propiedades)
{
    if (prop.Name != "id")
        campos.Append($"{prop.Name}=@{prop.Name},");                        
}
```

Então, **propriedades** não contem apenas **nome e cpf** como criado o objeto *oiginalmenre* mas tem todos os **atributos** do **objeto**. Os que entraram na criação seguem com seus valores mas os que não entraram na criação do **objetos** entram com valor **null**.

Como fazer pra não permitir a importação desses atributos que **NÃO** foram setadas na criação do onjeto?

Answer (score -1):

Minha solução:

No form:

```
var admStore = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    admStore["privilege"] = cb_privilege.Text;
    admStore["name"] = tb_name.Text;
    admStore["login"] = tb_login.Text;
    admStore["password"] = md5.RetornarMD5(tb_password.Text);
    admStore["bloq"] = cb_bloq.Text;
    admStore["datetime"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

admin.Grava(admStore);
```

No Model:

```
    public class Model
    {
        protected string table;

        protected MySqlConnection connection = MySql.Connect();

        public bool Grava(Dictionary<string,string> obj)
        {
            connection.Open();

            try
            {
                var campos = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (var field in obj)
                {
                    campos.Append($"{field.Key}=@{field.Key},");
                }

                string sql = "INSERT INTO " + this.table + " SET " + campos.ToString().Remove(campos.ToString().Length - 1);

                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);

                foreach (var field in obj)
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + field.Key, field.Value);
                }

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }

        }

.........
```

Obs.: Se tiverem uma melhor basta compartihar!